# Excel Pie chart format value and percent label independently

Tags: excel, charts, formatting, numbers

I want to label a pie chart with the abolute values and a percentage. When I show the values only,

[image: Pie chart with values labeled properly]

`[<1000000]0,00." KB";[<1000000000]0,00.." MB";0,00..." GB"` provides me the formatting I wish.
How can I keep custom formatting for the value and proper formatting for the percentage when I enable both in the Format Data Labels pane? So far it looks like the custom formatting only applies to the percentage and the value remains unformatted.

[image: Pie chart with value and percentage labels under the unintended application of custom formatting to the percentage part.]

However, if I change the number formatting to percent, this comes closer to what I want, but the value part is still no longer displayed in the correct formatting with KB, MB and GB.

[image]

Comment: You can have both, create a column of those values and use the custom formatting you need, next use this range for data labels i.e. the first option in labels option called value from cells

Comment: Thank you for this useful advice, of which I was well aware. However, this is not my preferred solution as it would require a major restructuring of a very large database.

I still try to understand if there is a way to independently format Value and Percentage if both is activated.